# Opening a new Finder *tab* from command line

Tags: finder, command-line

I'm wondering if there is a means of opening a new finder *tab* (not window) from the command line. I can do, e.g.,

```
open .
```

but this opens a new window. It would be nice to open a new tab in the most-recently active existing finder window.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please open Finder preferences and check "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" under General tab is enabled.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with, based on the answer at [How do you duplicate current open Finder view in new tab (Mavericks)?](https://superuser.com/questions/666762/how-do-you-duplicate-current-open-finder-view-in-new-tab-mavericks)

```
    function newtab()
{
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\"
    activate
    set t to target of Finder window 1
    set toolbar visible of window 1 to true
end tell
tell application \"System Events\"
    keystroke \"t\" using command down
end tell
tell application \"Finder\"
    set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file \"`pwd`\"
end tell" 1> /dev/null
}
```

All the escaped quotes isn't very elegant, but seemed to be necessary to allow the command substitution.

Thanks to Christopher Stone for pointing me in the direction of AppleScript! Unfortunately his solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You really can't via any “normal” shell commands, but you *can* run AppleScript via the shell to accomplish the task.

Here's a Bash function with the command `fnt` for “Finder New Tab”:

```
function fnt()
{
    osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to perform action "AXPress" of menu item "New Tab" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"'
}
```

Add the above `bash function` to your `~/.bash_profile` or `̃/.profile` file to use it. After adding, restart Terminal or use the `source` command in the current Terminal window to have access to the `fnt` function.

This *should* work on any version macOS that has the “New Tab” command in the “File” menu. You'll also need to add Terminal to: System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy Accessibility

I understand some improvement to AppleScript has been made in Mojave relative to tabs in the Finder, but I'm still using macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and can't test.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to be working for me. When I run the command, it opens a new Finder window, at the default starting directory. (It also prints out `action AXPress of menu item New Tab of menu File of menu bar item File of menu bar 1 of application process Finder`).

Comment: The first issue is odd – what version of macOS are you using?

Comment: The second issue can be eliminated by appending  ' 1> /dev/null' to the command in the function.

Comment: I'm on 10.12.6.

Comment: If you haven't added the Terminal.app to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility try doing that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Eventually I realized that the reason this wasn't working for me was because my shell window was in another Desktop from Finder. If I move the shell to the same Desktop then this works---although it doesn't open the path from the shell, which was my aim (although I realize I may have been less than completely clear about that in my original question).

Answer (score 0):

this would work

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to activate' \
  -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down' \
  -e 'tell application "Finder" to set the target of the front Finder window to (POSIX file (do shell script "pwd"))'
```